# Where is the "gdx" library located?

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to figure out where is this `gdx.so` file's location (it is native code, so I guess it should end with .so, but I am not sure).

[image: 1]

As you can see from the screenshot, there is a `libgdx.so` file, but I don't understand how does `System.loadLibrary("gdx");` work. I can't find any file with that name.

So, my question is, where is that `gdx` located ? or how does this line work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that when calling `System.loadLibrary("mylib");` the string `mylib` is automatically converted into `libmylib.so`. So this is how it actually works.